# How to change the copy file behavior in mac osx

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I used to use Ubuntu 
most of time, the command are same as Ubuntu
But there is a command annoys me.
it is cp (copy command)
because I often type cp -a FOLDER/ target 
to copy a file , however , the command will copy all the folder under FOLDER/ but not including FOLDER/ itself.
I know I can get what I want by using cp -a FOLDER target (without the slash in the tail)
it easily to  misuse the command.
Is there any way to change the behavior, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The command cp is a program in /bin so you could rename the cp command to another file, such as main_cp.exe and create a batch file (script) of your own called cp, which changes the call from what you type to what is actually required and then calls main_cp.exe.

However, if you're going to be using OSX a lot and perhaps on other people's machines, learning to train yourself to just not type the slash is probably going to be better in the long term.